# Unable to install Perlapi anymore?

Tags: linux, package, perlapi

I'm trying to follow the steps to fix Shutter's disabled edit button, and for that, you need to install `libgoo-canvas-perl`

I downloaded it, but when I install, I get:

```
libgoo-canvas-perl: Depends: perlapi-5.22.1 but it is not installable
```

What I can do?

Comment: Question should rather be titled "Unable to install libgoo-canvas-perl due to an outdated dependency on an old version of perl

Answer (score 0):

The archive pool site only seems to have the old package:

libgoo-canvas-perl_0.06-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb

(note the ubuntu1 version)

Use and install the newer version from launchpad which has the dependency updated for the newer version of perl.

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/bionic/amd64/libgoo-canvas-perl/0.06-2ubuntu3

(note the ubuntu3 version)